# Prefabs not selecting a specific object prefab in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So im working on a fighting Game and im spawning enemies with a prefab i made but when i try to fight them with ny fighting script it chosses a random enemy i spawned with the prefab

```
 IEnumerator Test()
{
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, 90);
    swing = true;
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    transform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
    swing = false;
}
public bool swing;


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
       
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Enemy" && swing == true ) 
        {
        
        Destroy(GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy"));
        }




    }
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGXbgdoMmoE
heres a video i made presenting the problem

Comment: Can we get a text description of the issue you are facing? It will help us better assist you with this issue.

Comment: @DekuDesu so as said i have a fighting game with a sword. and i habe an enemy prefab which are spawned around the map. when i attack it instead of destroying the enemy object it destroys a random enemy i spawned so my question is how do make it destroy the specific prefab i am attacking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you use

```
GameObject.FindWithTag("Enemy")
```

? This of course will return just the first found `GameObject` with according tag in the scene. Which can be **any**.

You already **know** the reference:

```
Destroy(collision.gameObject);
```

---

You should rather use `CompareTag` instead of `==` like

```
// Also the "swing" is cheaper to check so check it first
if (swing && collision.gameObject.CompareTag( "Enemy")) 
...
```